# Date format in jQuery dateTimePicker being ignored in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

Im using the JQuery dateTimePicker an a meteor app and most of the attributes I need to set when I render the control are working just fine. The dateFormat on the other hand is being ignored totally.

I'm setting things up with

```
Template.requestLayout.rendered = function(){
  $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    startDate: moment().day(12),
    defaultDate: moment().day(12),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: '0,1,2,3,6',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    autoclose: true
  });
```

and everything else is working fine. The date however is always being displayed with mm/dd/yyyy in the date field of the control.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Oh, the control is put on the form with

```
      <div class="input-group datetimepicker" id="reqDateTimePicker">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reqDate" data-format="YYYY/MM/DD"  readonly> -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reqDate" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
```

Neither of the input lines makes any difference it seems.

Ta.  Peter.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle link please.

Comment: Not sure I can Justin, not unless jsfiddle can run meteor templates?

Comment: are you sure this is related to meteor? In your code, meteor doesn't seem to play much of a role.

Comment: Absolutely not @Christian all I know is that dateFormat is not working while every thing else is.